# XSLT - Special Character transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have sample xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <node>Test</node>
    <?ABC Text &#x2013; <italic>Text</italic> more text?>
</doc>
```

I need to get the value of processing instruction ABC so I wrote following template,

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('ABC')[contains(.,'italic>')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
```

But it returns value,

```
Text &amp;#x2013; &lt;italic&gt;Text&lt;/italic&gt; more text
```

`&#x2013;` shows as `&amp;#x2013;` .. How can I avoid this to happen?

My expected output : `Text &#x2013; <italic>Text</italic> more text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, if supported by the processor and you serialize the result, is

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('ABC')[contains(.,'italic>')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/naZXpWH